# Laravel Tailwind PostCSS issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css, postcss

I have an issue with my Laravel app, I'm building the app using TailWindCSS for styling.

However, whenever I try and run the `npm run dev` command it goes through the cycle of purging unused CSS to lower file size (I'm sure you all know what it does :P)

However, before it can finish it errors out with the following error message (above the '}' at the start are just css classes that I presume are being purged):

```
} is not a PostCSS plugin
    at Processor.normalize (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:63:15)
    at new Processor (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:10:25)
    at postcss (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:26:10)
    at LazyResult.runOnRoot (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:339:16)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:391:26)
    at async Object.loader (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:97:14)
    at processResult (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:721:19)
    at C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:827:5
    at C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:142:7)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
(node:6980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:667:9)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:319:17)
    at Object.module.exports.fileCommand (C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\node-notifier\lib\utils.js:76:13)
    at C:\Users\Adzei\OneDrive\Website Projects\naso_webapp\node_modules\node-notifier\notifiers\toaster.js:145:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Now, if I comment out the `require('postcss')` from my `webpack.mix.js` it builds with no errors. I also attempted to use the postcss-import, which builds fine as well but it doesn't actually remove any unused CSS.

This is the `.postCss` section of the webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('postcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ]);
```

and finally here is my TailWindCSS config:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/**/*.js',
        './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add tailwindcss as a plugin like that. Just put that code in your app.css. And delete requires from `webpack.mix.js`.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: I only did everything the way Tailwinds Documentation said to do it, I have also watched multiple courses on Udemy and YouTube and they all took this route as well with no issues. Tailwinds laravel documentation states it requires the .postcss section in the webpack.mix.js file...

Also, I do have the

````
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
````

In my app.css

Comment: Delete requires from `webpack.mix.js`. You are requiring post.css inside post.css

Comment: This was due to documentation stating to do so, if I don't include postcss there, it never runs and the css gets built with ALL classes and JS included making the files a lot bigger than needed... I need postcss to run...